# jQuery droppable accept links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I have created an unordered list that I would give the ability to accept and add dragged links such as hyperlinks, or favorites etc.

I have created a droppable area:

```
$("#dropArea").droppable({
    hoverClass:'hovered',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
            $("#urlList ul").append('<li>'+ui.draggable.text()+'</li>');
    }
});
```

This div currently accepts other draggable objects, but not the objects I want. I am not sure where to go from here, or whether this is even possible.

thanks

Comment: Could you [provide a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I have a hard time visualising jQuery UI code (for some unknown reason)...

Comment: this should help you visualise what I am trying to do, although it obviously doesn't work yet! http://jsfiddle.net/7S4hz/

Answer (score 0):

Use accept property:

```
$("#dropArea").droppable({
    accept: 'a', //for all links, you can use class ie. 'a.draggable'
    hoverClass:'hovered',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
            $("#urlList ul").append('<li>'+ui.draggable.text()+'</li>');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. It does not seem to be working though, please see http://jsfiddle.net/7S4hz/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your jsfiddle code.

```
("#favList ul").append ...
```

should be

```
("#favList").append ...
```

otherwise you don't select anything because your ul element has the favlist id.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have fixed it..however the code at the moment is not even getting this far as the drop function is not being triggered.

Comment: Are the other objects marked as draggable?
Like $("a").draggable();